# Twilio Functions work individually but they do not work correctly when I use them in Studio Flows

Tags: email, twilio, sms

I have created a couple of functions that work fine by themselves.

**Function # 1 - SMS to email**. This sends an email upon receipt of SMS at Twilio number:

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const requestBody = {
      personalizations: [{ to: [{ email: context.TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS }] }],
      from: { email: context.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS },
      subject: `New SMS message from: ${event.From}`,
      content: [
        {
          type: 'text/plain',
          value: event.Body
        }
      ]
    };
   
    got.post('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${context.SENDGRID_API_KEY}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    })
      .then(response => {
        let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
        callback(null, twiml);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        callback(err);
      });
};
```

**Function # 2 - Forward SMS.** This forwards incoming SMS received at Twilio number to two mobile phone numbers:

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message(`From: ${event.From}. Body: ${event.Body}`, {
    to: context.ASDA_PHONE_NUMBER,
  });
  twiml.message(`From: ${event.From}. Body: ${event.Body}``, {
    to: context.MY_PHONE_NUMBER,
  });
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Both functions are working fine when linked directly to the number individually as the only service or function responding to incoming SMS.

However, when I use these functions in a Studio Flow with Run Function widgets they do not work as expected. Function #1 does not work at all. Function #2 works partially, but it seems the event.From and event.Body variables are undefined and the text of the SMS message received by the mobile phones reads "From: undefined. Body: undefined".

This is the structure of the Studio Flow with the two Run Function widgets:

[Structure of the Studio Flow with a Run Function widget for each function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwdhA.png)

It seems context data, like context.MY_PHONE_NUMBER is accesible to the functions. Otherwise the second function would not be able to forward SMS. However it appears event data, like event.From, is not accessible to the functions.

I am guessing the "event" parameter in function(context, event, callback) is not being passed to the functions by the Studio Flow and I need to pass this information as parameters, but I have not found a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In the Run Function widget, you can add parameters. These are what will show up on your `event` object in the Function.

You can use Liquid template syntax for the values to expected keys in your Run Function widget

Comment: Hi, thank you. I know I can add parameters and, as I mentioned in my question I was guessing I needed to pass those values as parameters. My question is how to do this properly. Does Studio Flow see the "event" variables, like event.From?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio support helped me solve this.
I added the following function parameters to the functions:

Function #1:
Key: **Body**
Value: **{{trigger.message.Body}}**

Function #2:
Key: **From**
Value: **{{trigger.message.From}}**

With that, both functions work perfectly within the flow.